# Why does "true" == true show false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, equals

[MDC describes the `==` operator as follows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible.

With this in mind, I would evaluate `"true" == true` as follows:

1. Are they of the same type? **No**
2. Is either operand a number or boolean? **Yes**
3. Can we convert both to a number? **No** (`isNaN(Number("true")) // true`)
4. Is either operand a string? **Yes**
5. Can we convert the other operand to a string? **Yes** (`String(true) === "true" // true`)

I've ended up with the strings `"true"` and `"true"`, which should evaluate to `true`, but JavaScript shows false.

What have I missed?

Comment: Relevant: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.1

Comment: With so much JavaScript around, world is a scary place: `if("true" == true) {console.log("yes")} else {console.log("no")}; if("true") {console.log("yes")} else {console.log("no")}` ---> "no yes"

Comment: I gotta say, I'm surpised, and that is sooo stupid that this happens. Yet another reason to always always always use ===

Comment: @user1068352 check the chaos :) https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Because `"true"` is converted to `NaN`, while `true` is converted to `1`. So they differ.

Like you reported, both are converted to numbers, because at least `true` can be (see Erik Reppen's comment), and then compared.

Comment: Can you tell me when the step `Can we convert both to a number?` will ever be false then? If even `NaN` is a number, how can this step ever fail?

Comment: Either vs. neither. If both would result in NaN they would switch to string evaluation. If only one can be converted, there's still a number comparison.

Comment: There are actually some odd objects in Javascript that behave quite oddly. For example, XML documents in IE<9 raise an error when you try to convert them to numbers.

Comment: You can see the conversions yourself by doing `Number(true)` and `Number('true')`

Answer (score 21):

The `==` comparison operator is [defined in ECMA 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) as:

4. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(x) is Number and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(y) is String,
   return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(y).
5. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(x) is String and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(y) is Number,
   return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(x) == y.
6. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(x) == y.
7. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(y).

So, "true" == true is evaluated as:

1. "true" == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(true)   *(via rule 7)*
2. "true" == 1
3. [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)("true") == 1   *(via rule 5)*
4. NaN == 1

===> false

Answer (score 4):

Acording to The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

if one of the oprends is a boolean and other is not, boolean is converter to number 0 or 1. so `true == "true"` is false.

Comment: Did I infer right in the following way?

"true" == true becomes "true" == 1 and then becomes "true" == "1"

That's why they return false?

Answer (score 2):

The equality operators (`==` and `!=`) use the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) to compare two operands.

#### `"true" == true`

Since `"true"` is `String` and `true` is `Boolean`, we need to return the result of `"true" == Number(true)` (step `7` in the algorithm), which is `"true" == 1`.

#### `"true" == 1`

Since `"true"` is `String` and `1` is `Number`, we need to return the result of `Number("true") == 1` (step `5` in the algorithm). `Number("true")` returns `NaN`.
Now we have `NaN == 1`.

#### `NaN == 1`

Now both operands are of the same type (`Number`).
Acording to the algorithm, if both operands are `Number` and one of them is `NaN`, `false` is returned (step `1.c.i` in the algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Explaining considering the scenario **true == "true"**.
Straightway, the above returns **false**, however, our expectation was **true**
JavaScript uses **Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**, so according to the algorithm

```
true == "true"

// If one of the operands is Boolean, convert the Boolean operand to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false
ConvertToNumber(true) == "true"

1 == "true"

// When the algorithm finds the above statements, it thinks that it needs to do one more conversion - 
// "When comparing a number to a string, try to convert the string to a numeric value"
1 == ConvertToNumber("true)
1 == NaN

// Which returns false
```