# Why javascript comparison ("true" == true) is false?

Tags: javascript, ecma

I'm trying to understand the following case:

```
> "1" === 1
false

> "1" == 1
true

> true === 1
false

> true == 1
true

> "true" === true
false

> "true" == true
false
```

Why javascript comparison ("true" == true) is false?

Also, what is the proper way to compare this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363659/why-does-true-true-show-false-in-javascript).

In essence,  `"true"` is converted to NaN, while `true` is converted to 1 (which is a boolean. Hence, they differ.

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean in the comparison is going to have an implicit conversion to Number (0/1) so 1=true gets true, but "true" == true (1), so the string can't be equal to Number, it gets false