# Check JSON in JS for Fals/true

Tags: javascript

I have a json that is read with ajax in php.  One of the variables is either true or false.  I am having trouble getting it to work with an if statement.

```
   "batsman1": {
    "Name": "Anvesh *",
    "Runs": "0",
    "Balls": "0",
    "StrikeRate": "-",
    "currentlyOnStrike": true
  },
  "batsman2": {
    "Name": "Anuj ",
    "Runs": "3",
    "Balls": "2",
    "StrikeRate": "150.00",
    "currentlyOnStrike": false
  },
```

JS:

```
            var onstrike1 = data.batsman1.currentlyOnStrike;
            var onstrike2 = data.batsman2.currentlyOnStrike;
            if(onstrike1 == 'true'){
                document.getElementById("onstrike1").innerHTML = "*";
            }else{document.getElementById("onstrike1").innerHTML = onstrike1;}

            if(onstrike2 == 'true'){
                document.getElementById("onstrike2").innerHTML = "*";
            }else{document.getElementById("onstrike2").innerHTML = onstrike2;}
```

It is always showing false in this script.  What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the prblem is that you're comparing onstrike1 with a string. So,

**Do this**

```
if(onstrike1)
```

**Or**

```
if(onstrike1 === true)
```

**Instead of this**

```
if(onstrike1 == 'true')
```

*You're comparing onstrike1 value to a string while true/false is of Boolean type*

Comment: For added context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11363709/12431728

Answer (score 2):

JSON booleans will be translated to Javascript booleans, so you can simply just:

```
if(onstrike1 === true)
```