# Why does true == "true" returns false?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, compare

Assume we have a condition, where a String `"true"` is compared to Boolean `true`. It returns `false`, though `true == '1'` returns `true`. If you do `true == !!"true"`, this will return `true`, so it should mean, that since the beginning `"true"` was `true`. Is there any specific logic, that I am missing, or it just works with string representation of `0` and `1`?

```js
console.log(true == 'true')
```

Comment: "*so it should mean, that since the beginning "true"*" no, that doesn't actually logically follow. `!!42` is also `true` but `true == 42` is still `false` because they aren't loosely equal. `==` doesn't compare for what *converts* to `true`, after all, it compares both operands by converting them to a common base.

Comment: Added my two cents here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199489/6840789

Answer (score 1):

Because "true" is converted to NaN, while true is converted to 1. So they differ.

-- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11363709/14251221)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really tricky:)

Comment: I'll add that the reason `!!"true"` returns true is that the double bang operator converts an `Object` into a `boolean`, returning `true` as long as the operand is not false, e.g. `0`, `null`, `undefined`, etc. Notably, `!!"0"` and `!!"1"` return `true` whereas `!!0` returns `false`. This is because the operands in the `true` examples are non-empty strings.