Ternary Operator evaluating wrongly?
I am trying to build a trivial workflow using GitHub Actions consisting of the following jobs:

Infrastructure Provisioning
Application Deployment
Status Callback

Thereby, I am using a ternary operator to determine whether 'OK' or 'NOK' is passed as an input variable to the Status Callback job.
(offical documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/evaluate-expressions-in-workflows-and-actions#example)
However, my ternary operator seems to be behaving weirdly based on the following scenarios I have tested.
The code underlying my investigations/scenarios is always the same apart from the ternary operator determining the status:
  Status-Callback-Generic-A:
    # needs: [Infrastructure_Provisioning, Dummy_Application_Deployment]
    needs: [Dummy_Application_Deployment]
    if: ${{ always() }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/status-callback.yml
    with:
      connectionId: ${{ inputs.connectionId }}
      status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Scenario A
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Scenario B
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Scenario C
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == true && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Scenario D
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == 1 && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Scenario E
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == '1' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

Below table depicts the results from above scenario-specific code snippets. In summary: No single scenario seems to work properly.



is_success
expected status
status(A)
status(B)
status(C)
status(D)
status(E)




true
OK
NOK
OK
NOK
NOK
NOK


false
NOK
NOK
OK
NOK
NOK
NOK



Notes from official documentation:
(https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/evaluate-expressions-in-workflows-and-actions#operators)

job outputs evaluate as strings
GitHub transforms non-matching types to numbers. In case of Boolean:

true returns 1
false returns 0



Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with my conditionals?
The is_success is based on the steps in the respective workflow
name: Dummy Application Deployment

on:
  workflow_call:      
    outputs:
      is_success: 
        description: Dummy Description
        value: ${{ jobs.build_and_deploy_dummy_application.outputs.is_success }}

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_dummy_application:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      is_success: |
          ${{ 
          steps.failing-step.outcome == 'success' &&
          steps.build-dummy-application.outcome == 'success' &&
          steps.deploy-dummy-application.outcome == 'success'
          }}
steps:
# omitted


How are you setting is_success?

added a code snippet on the bottom of the entry. It has to be noted that the is_success is correctly populated.

I would guess javascript https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=javascript+%3D%3D+true https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363659/why-does-true-true-show-false-in-javascript What is the actual value of needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success? Is it possible to run: echo ${{needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success}}?

I do indeed have a "logger-job" that does exactly that and the is_success seems to be what it is supposed to be e.g. if the Dummy_Application_Deployment outputs true it is indeed true Output of Dummy_Application_Deployment is_success = true and vice versa.

@NicolasKilchenmann: Apparently, the scenario A should work. Have you tried returning the status instead of true/false?

It seems that I am not alone with this issue: GitHub Issue 1 and Github Issue 2

@Azeem Scenario A is also not behaving correctly as it results in both cases in 'NOK'.

When is_success is set like this:
is_success: |
  ${{ 
    steps.failing-step.outcome == 'success' &&
    steps.build-dummy-application.outcome == 'success' &&
    steps.deploy-dummy-application.outcome == 'success'
  }}

using YAML's literal style indicator i.e. |, there is always a trailing newline at the end which makes it a multiline output.
Adding the strip block chomping indicator i.e. - should fix this:
is_success: |-
  ${{ ... }}

Better yet, to avoid scenarios where intermediate newlines may also cause such issues, prefer using fold with strip i.e. >- instead:
is_success: >-
  ${{ ... }}

You may experiment with https://yaml-multiline.info/ for different use cases of multiline strings.
With this fix, the comparison against string literal 'true' or 'false' should work as expected:
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}


Given above, you may dry run all your scenarios to figure out why some comparisons work and others won't. The comparison was being performed against a multiline string:
'true\n' == 'true' (false)

For scenario B:
status: ${{ needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

needs.Dummy_Application_Deployment.outputs.is_success is only being evaluated for a null or not-null value. It's populated so it's a not-null value that's why it's evaluated to true ('OK').

Excuse my belated response! Most likely I would never have figured this out on my own... (one reason more to not like YAML ;))
Learning: Do expression evaluations in a single line ;)
For everyone interested please find below the action files highlighting the issue
main.yml
name: Main Flow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      host:
        type: text
        required: true
      connectionId:
        type: text
        required: true

jobs:
  Job-1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job-1.yml    

  Job-2:
    needs: [ Job-1 ]
    if: ${{ always() }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: log-outputs-of-job-1
        run: |
          echo "Job-1 - is_success_naive = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_one_liner }}"
          echo "Job-1 - is_success_naive = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_naive }}"
          echo "Job-1 - is_success_chomp = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_chomp}}"
          echo "Job-1 - is_success_other = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_other }}"
          echo "Job-1 - step-1_outcome = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.step-1_outcome }}"
          echo "Job-1 - step-1_outcome = ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.step-2_outcome }}"
      
  Status-Callback:
    needs: [ Job-1 ]
    if: ${{ always() }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/status-callback.yml
    with:
      host: ${{ inputs.host }}
      connectionId: ${{ inputs.connectionId }}
      status_one_liner: ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_one_liner == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}
      status_naive: ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_naive == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}
      status_chomp: ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_chomp == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}
      status_other: ${{ needs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_other == 'true' && 'OK' || 'NOK' }}

job-1.yml
name: Job 1

on: 
  workflow_call:
    outputs:
      is_success_one_liner:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_one_liner }}
      is_success_naive:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_naive }}
      is_success_chomp:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_chomp }}
      is_success_other:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.is_success_other }}
      step-1_outcome:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.step-1_outcome }}
      step-2_outcome:
        value: ${{ jobs.Job-1.outputs.step-2_outcome }}
        
jobs:
  Job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      #Working (single line): 
      is_success_one_liner: ${{ steps.step-1.outcome == 'success' && steps.step-2.outcome == 'success' }}
      
      #Naive (|)
      is_success_naive: |
        ${{ 
          steps.step-1.outcome == 'success' &&
          steps.step-2.outcome == 'success'
         }}
      
      #Chomp (|-)
      is_success_chomp: |-
        ${{ 
          steps.step-1.outcome == 'success' &&
          steps.step-2.outcome == 'success'
        }}
      
      #Other indicator (>-)
      is_success_other: >-
        ${{ 
          steps.step-1.outcome == 'success' &&
          steps.step-2.outcome == 'success'
         }}
      step-1_outcome: ${{ steps.step-1.outcome }}
      step-2_outcome: ${{ steps.step-2.outcome }}
    steps:
      - id: step-1
        run: echo "Hello from step-1"
      - id: step-2
        #run: echo "Hello from step-2"
        run: failing-command
      - id: log-previous-outcomes
        run: |
          echo "Outcome step-1 = ${{ steps.step-1.outcome }}"
          echo "Outcome step-2 = ${{ steps.step-2.outcome }}"

status-callback.yml
name: Status Callback

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      host:
        type: string
        required: true
      connectionId:
        type: string
        required: true
      status_one_liner:
        type: string
        required: true
      status_naive:
        type: string
        required: true
        default: 'naive'
      status_chomp:
        type: string
        required: true
        default: 'chomp'
      status_other:
        type: string
        required: true
        default: 'other'

jobs:
  Status-Callback:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Log Input Variables
        id: log-input-variables
        run: |
          echo "host" = ${{ inputs.host }}
          echo "connectionId = ${{ inputs.connectionId }}"
          echo "status_one_liner = ${{ inputs.status_one_liner }}"
          echo "status_naive = ${{ inputs.status_naive }}"
          echo "status_chomp = ${{ inputs.status_chomp }}"
          echo "status_other = ${{ inputs.status_other }}"
      
      - name: Status Callback (One-Liner)
        id: status-callback-one-liner
        continue-on-error: true
        run: curl -X "POST" ${{ inputs.host }}/${{ inputs.connectionId }}/${{ inputs.status_one_liner }}
        
      - name: Status Callback (Naive)
        id: status-callback-naive
        continue-on-error: true
        run: curl -X "POST" ${{ inputs.host }}/${{ inputs.connectionId }}/${{ inputs.status_naive }}      
      
      - name: Status Callback (Chomp)
        id: status-callback-chomp
        continue-on-error: true
        run: curl -X "POST" ${{ inputs.host }}/${{ inputs.connectionId }}/${{ inputs.status_chomp }}      
      
      - name: Status Callback (Other)
        id: status-callback-other
        continue-on-error: true
        run: curl -X "POST" ${{ inputs.host }}/${{ inputs.connectionId }}/${{ inputs.status_other }}

